# How to align two DOM layers with text on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is to align one DOM layer (background) on top of the other (foreground). Both layers contain the exact same text.

The *foreground* is just plain text.

The *background* contains `span`s of the same text.

For some reason, the `span`s with just white spaces are messing up the alignment. I guess it has something to do with `white-space` CSS property.

What am I missing?

```css
.foreground,
.background {
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.foreground {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background {
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.color {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="foreground">‘Holy cow, he’s right, probably 90 percent of the stories involve aliens.'</div>
      <div class="background"><div class="section"><span class="space"><span>‘</span></span><span class="color"><span>Holy</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>cow</span></span><span class="space"><span>, </span></span><span class="color"><span>he’s</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>right</span></span><span class="space"><span>, </span></span><span class="color"><span>probably</span></span><span class="space"><span> 90 </span></span><span class="color"><span>percent</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>of</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>the</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>stories</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>involve</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>aliens</span></span><span class="space"><span>.'</span></span></div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use font-kerning: none; to fix the problem. In most cases, font-kerning: none; will not even be noticeable, except perhaps to the very diligent designers who have a very keen eye for fonts.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that's because of how a certain typeface handles ligatures and kerning—spacing between specific combinations of characters/glyphs. In your background, the characters are all broken up into individual words because you are wrapping them in individual `<span>` elements. This makes the browser render the whitespace between the glyphs slightly differently.

This hypothesis makes sense when you notice that the first "offset" comes right around where the first `,` character is introduced: the font rendering probably knows that it should use slightly different spacing between a word and a trailing comma, which causes the discrepancy to happen:

[image]

Another proof is to use a monospace font, and you can see you problem going away:

```css
.foreground,
.background {
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: monospace;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.foreground {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background {
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.color {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="foreground">‘Holy cow, he’s right, probably 90 percent of the stories involve aliens.'</div>
      <div class="background"><div class="section"><span class="space"><span>‘</span></span><span class="color"><span>Holy</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>cow</span></span><span class="space"><span>, </span></span><span class="color"><span>he’s</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>right</span></span><span class="space"><span>, </span></span><span class="color"><span>probably</span></span><span class="space"><span> 90 </span></span><span class="color"><span>percent</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>of</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>the</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>stories</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>involve</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>aliens</span></span><span class="space"><span>.'</span></span></div></div>
    </div>
```

<strike>There is unfortunately no straight-forward solution to your problem, because the spacing between words and trailing commas do not seem to be affected by the `font-variant-ligatures: none;` declaration. My advice is that you might want to simply mirror the markup in both the background and the foreground elements.</strike>

You can force the browser to disable custom kerning of fonts, which should fix the issue. This can be done by using `font-kerning: none` (credit to @Kashif Imran for pointing it out in the comments):

```css
.foreground,
.background {
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-kerning: none;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.foreground {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background {
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.color {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="foreground">‘Holy cow, he’s right, probably 90 percent of the stories involve aliens.'</div>
      <div class="background"><div class="section"><span class="space"><span>‘</span></span><span class="color"><span>Holy</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>cow</span></span><span class="space"><span>, </span></span><span class="color"><span>he’s</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>right</span></span><span class="space"><span>, </span></span><span class="color"><span>probably</span></span><span class="space"><span> 90 </span></span><span class="color"><span>percent</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>of</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>the</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>stories</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>involve</span></span><span class="space"><span> </span></span><span class="color"><span>aliens</span></span><span class="space"><span>.'</span></span></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You described the problem correctly. I think there is a way i.e: font-kerning: none; will fix it.